# How to use length function in lpad, where the length of lpad is decided based on the column value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

I have a column which contains value as `val a = List(123,656,453,7889,64396)`.
I want to use lpad like `lpad(col("a"), a.length, "0")`. Basically, I am not sure of the length of number in the list so I have to check each number length and then lpad it with Os.

Basically I have this input dataframe:
`(00123,000656,000453,007889,064396)`. And applying

```
val getRandom = udf((seed: String) => new Random(seed).shuffle(seed.toCharArray.iterator).mkString("")
```

on the dataframe. But my output of the randomisation removes the 0s. Which I want to lpad it.

```
| inpCol     |  newCol |
------------------------
|  154200231 |     123 |
| 2343000566 |     656 |
| 6543000453 |     345 |
```

Comment: Do you mean _left pad_ or what is `lpad` exactly?

Comment: lpad function exactly

Comment: Can you show your desired output?

Comment: OK, I have a solution in mind. Do I get that right, that `a` contains these numbers as strings already?

Comment: I am using val a= sqlContext.table(tbl).select("colNm").collect.map(_(0)).toString

Comment: @krzysztof I have updated my question. The desired output should be. (00123,000656,000453,007889,064396)

Comment: I think this is a follow up of your question you asked earlier. Can you Create a input dataframe And put the schema and output og show here

Comment: val df = sqlContext.table(tableNm).withColumn("newCol", getRandom(expr("substring(trim(inpCol),5,length(trim(inpCol)))")) - inpCol is my input col - schema output in original description.

Comment: @B.Amrita : How do u decide on this logic?
123 has to be 00123;
656 has to be 000656;
64396 has to be 064396 ? 
Because, only 123 input value has a length of 5 after lpadding - rest all have a length of 6 after lpadding. Can you please be more clear ?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to first find out the maximal length of any number string you have in `a` with

```scala
val a = List(123,656,453,7889,64396)
val length = a.map(_.length).max

lpad(col("a"), length, "0")
```

Then use that for padding all of them.

Comment: This applies to all the numbers.. but I want each number lpadded as per the no.of digits.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment to @Yann's post that you want each number to be lpadded as per the number of digits:

You can try this.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lpad


def lpadFunc() = {
   expr("lpad(a, length(a)*2, '0')").as("LPAD")
}

df.select("a", lpadFunc())
```

Output:

```
+--------------+----------+
|       a      |    LPAD  |
+--------------+----------+
|           111|    000111|
|          2224|  00002224|
|         33435|0000033435|
+--------------+----------+
```

***What this function does is:*** It will take the length of the column "a" and doubles it - then lpadding is applied. So that, the same number of zeros as the length of each value in the column will get lpadded to each column value.